# Linq To SQL where condition with IEnumerable

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008

I have the following query where I want to filter out certain codes for deletion. It is for a payroll program and depending on the user running it, it should only allow deletion of employees under a users list:

```
IEnumerable<int> employeeIdList;    <----contains employee Ids under a certain user

var processDataTemps = tempProcessDataService.GetAllProcessDataTemps();
```

Sample results from above query

```
Code  Name  U_Employee_ID  U_month  U_PD_code   U_Amount    U_Balance  U_taxyear    
0     0     1              2        SYS037    24308.500000  0.000000    2013
1     1     1              2        SYS014    50470.000000  0.000000    2013
10    10    8              2        SYS024    7541.000000   0.000000    2013
13    13    7              2        SYS037    7541.000000   0.000000    2013
17    17    7              2        SYS024    7541.000000   0.000000    2013
```

My question is how do I modify the processDataTemps query to return the Codes (`Code` Column) for only the employee Ids that are contained in the  IEnumerable employeeIdList?

Ie. Such that if employeeIdList contains only 1 and 7, the modified processDataTemps query should return the `Code` values 0, 1 and 13 and 17. 
(Using SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using C#:

```
var processDataTemps = tempProcessDataService.GetAllProcessDataTemps()
                                             .Where(d => employeeIdList.Contains(d.U_Employee_ID))
                                             .Select(d => d.Code);
```